# alignment of a c array - alignment of array elements is greater than element size

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, alignment, typedef

Consider the following C code:

```
typedef __attribute__((aligned(16))) signed int    INT32;

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) 
{
    INT32                   my_array[255];
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it returns the error:

```
alignment_problem.c: In function ‘main’:
alignment_problem.c:7:2:error: alignment of array elements is greater than element size
INT32                   my_array[255];
```

I have a program that's not compiling due to this error.

Is there a way to define `INT32` in a way that the alignment will work?

I am aware that `clang` compiles this code without error, but I would like to know if there is a way to compile the code with `gcc`.

**EDIT**: The problem is, that the typedef `INT32` is one of a big program. So the solution I am searching for is to alter the definition of `INT32`, so that the program will compile and run.

Comment: Is your intention to have every element of the array aligned on a 16-byte boundary?

Comment: this is a question about gcc. tag it gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to align int not the array. Options you have is that you can make a typedef with known number of elements in array and align it accordingly.

```
typedef signed int  INT32[255] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) 
{
    INT32                   my_array;
    return 0;
}
```

or you can align it each time you use an array that needs to be aligned.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) 
{
    signed int my_array[255] __attribute__((aligned(16)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need a typedef for `INT32` that does not need alteration of the program code. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately  you cannot, because INT32 is not 16 bytes long so logically there's no way of aligning it.